# Vaadin7 with mybatis and Spring

Tags: eclipse, vaadin7, gradle-eclipse, spring-mybatis, vaadin4spring

i am new to Vaadin and Mybatis-Spring.

My UI class could not invoke the Service class using the @Autowired annotation. I have appended @Service for the service class.

My view:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("test")
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@SpringView(name = TestUI.ID)
public class TestUI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = TestUI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
@Autowired 
    UserService service;    
    UserModel model;
```

My application context.xml is under the resources folder.

```
<ct:annotation-config/>
<ct:component-scan base-package="com.example.test" />
<ct:component-scan base-package="com.example.service" />
<ct:component-scan base-package="com.example.model" />
<ct:component-scan base-package="com.example.mapper" />
```

DevContext.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<bean id="DEVdataSource" destroy-method="close"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="" />
    <property name="" value="" />
    <property name="" value="" />
    <property name="" value="" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="50" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dual"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="connectionInitSqls">
        <list>
            <value>ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=null</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- setup mybatis bean -->
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="DEVdataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="userMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.example.mapper.Mapper" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- automatically find mappers -->
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.example.mapper.**.mapper" />
</bean>
```

ServiceDevContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example"></context:component-scan>
```

Web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:resources/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
           org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The code is not working, kindly help me to figure out what i missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `@SpringUI` instead of `@SpringView` on the UI subclass, and you also need to use `SpringVaadinServlet` instead of `VaadinServlet`, the best is probably just to remove your static `Servlet` class that inherits from VaadinServlet, and the spring addon will use the correct servlet instead.

I would also recommend to get rid of the xml-config, unless you happen to like it. Using Spring Boot with Vaadin is supported on start.spring.io, it's a pretty easy way to bootstrap your project files and config.